# Launcher not over full length of screen

Tags: unity, launcher

I want to change the appearance of my ubuntu launcher so that not the whole length of my left screen side is occupied. I would like it to be similar to [this](http://macforbeginners.com/media/images/6-default-desktop.jpg) but on the left hand side of my screen. I tried Compiz, but I didnt find an option for this. Do I need to install a particular theme or can I change this option somewhere?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thank you all for your help!

Lena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't make launcher like that but you may try [cairo-dock](http://glx-dock.org/)**(sudo apt-get install cairo-dock)** or [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) **(sudo apt-get install docky)** to add custom dock for ubuntu. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I can completely remove the default dock? Because now the two docks are overlapping!!

Comment: I think you can remove one dock using configurations and if you would like use dock alone you can log in using light-dm menu(if you use cairo-dock)